# How to find variables dynamically created, but not with extract?

Tags: php

I'm working on an old site, written by somebody else, and they've done something equivalent to `extract($_POST)` somewhere in there code. But they didn't use the function extract.

The application was originally designed for PHP3 (yes, old), then it was ported to PHP4, and now I'm porting it to PHP5.

Does anyone know of what function it could be? Or, any way of finding it out? I've tried using PHPStorm's 'GoTo -> Declaration' but that wasn't it....

I've scanned the documents for the variable and there is no other reference to it, so its being generated by a function equivalent to extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) setting. Check the php.ini file on the server and see if it's turned on. If it's on you should turn it off and make all the necessary changes to the code to fix it (as part of your porting to PHP 5).

Another relevant page after checking the other link in this post: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: That was it! Thanks for that,  it was doing my head in looking for the code doing it, but it wasn't code, it was php.ini setting!

Comment: You're welcome. The register_globals setting being turned on can cause major security flaws as anyone can add arguments to the query string (or POST / Cookies) in an http request and they immediately become set variables in your code. That is why it is deprecated and highly recommended to be turned off.

Comment: I'll investigate each code piece and remove any dependency to it, but for now, sort of just needed to get the server back up and running. Huge help though :).

Answer (score 1):

May be used something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  ${$key} = $value;
}
```

Comment: Hmm that is def' a possibility! Thanks for the idea, ill investigate for that